# How to make sense out of an object returned in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {           
                    // ? :)
                    alert (dataString);


                },
                error : function(data) 
                {
                    alert("ajax error, json: " + data);

                    //for (var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; ++i) 
                    //{
                    //  alert (json[i]);
                    //}
                }
            });
```

And when I use it, I get in the alert something cryptic like this: `object XMLHTTPReqest`

How do I actually get the value that was passed in from the AJAX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a couple ways:

```
console.log(data); // allows you to view your object in a tree in the console
```

or

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // alerts a serialized string of the object
```

or in chrome/safari and firefox (firebug) set a break point and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the Firefox plugin called FireBug?  That's the first place I start as it will show you the exact structure, and data, of the json object returned.

from there it's a simple matter of coding in the object names etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox - Download Firebug. A must for any web dev.

Chome: instead of alert, do "console.log(data);" This should spit out the object and you can view its properties in the console (hit F12 for that).

Alternatively, write "debugger;" right before your alert and the browser will pause execution. You need to have Firebug running or Chrome Dev Tools open.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're alerting `dataString`, not anything returned from the server, at least in the `success` callback. `.ajax()` callback signatures look like this: `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`, so if you're getting real data back, it can be accessed like any JSON object, via the `data` parameter. In `error` it's `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`, so if that's what you're talking about, it kind of makes sense.

Use Firebug/Chrome/proxy/etc. to make sure what you're getting back from the server is what you expect, or just log it to the console.

Comment: yeah I am getting some string back in the error case. I just can't get at that string somehow.  It is wrapped up in the object.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the error handler.

The signature for the jQuery AJAX error handler is

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
>
> *A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred*

You cannot get the "data" returned as there is no data, just an error.

Comment: Well, that's not completely true, the server can return data, can't it? And the [jqXHR includes responseText and responseXML properties](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHRhttp://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Comment: @Dave True, however I doubt it will be the "data" as the OP wants it

Comment: Depends on what's happening on the server side, I reckon.